# WLResourceRequest over SSL with untrusted certificate

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing an hybrid application ( Android , iOS )
and we are facing an issue communicating with our backend services.

We are using untrusted certificate in the development environment and this lead to an error invoking the services using WLResourceRequest in the hybrid code.

The error on the android platform is the following:

java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

And reading from android logcat comes out this:

04-20 12:50:04.300 9427-9450/com.myApp D/wl.resource_request: WLResourceRequest.handleOnFailure in WLResourceRequest.java:658 :: Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again.
04-20 12:50:04.308 9427-9450/com.myApp D/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLResourceRequestPlugin: WLResourceRequestPlugin$1$1.onFailure in WLResourceRequestPlugin.java:92 :: inside WLResourceRequestPlugin failure

How can we manage to pass through the certificate validation? or is there something we can do to properly invoke the services?

Answer (score 1):

You can overcome this by adding the CA certificate to your device. 
Go to `Settings -> Security -> Install from SD card` and install the CA certificate to the device.